# Python plotly dynamic plot

Tags: python, dynamic, plotly

I've been trying to perform a visualization with Plotly, but my problem is that I need it to be dynamic. Meaning if I have the code:

```
import plotly.express as px 

data = [1, 5, 4, 7, 5, 2, 3, 9]
data_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 5] 

area_chart = px.area(data, title='Title')
area_chart.show()
```

then how do I append 'data_2' to 'data' so that the numbers from 'data_2' appear dynamically on the chart after it's created every 0.5s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to do it will depend on the environment in which you are creating the plot.
In Jupyter notebook you can do it as follows:

```
import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# initialize and display plot
fig = go.FigureWidget()
fig.add_scatter(y=np.random.randint(0,10, 5), fill='tozeroy')
display(fig)

# modify plot using new data
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    fig.data[0].y = np.random.randint(0,10, 5)
```

This gives:

[image: animated plotly]

Outside Jupyter notebook, you can use Dash.